# "Procedure successfully completed", but does not show the output, even when it should return values

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, in-clause

I have created a stored procedure in SQL Developer (Oracle):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE Procedure SP_test
    (Identificadores IN varchar,
     separador IN varchar,
     codigo IN char,
     resultSet out sys_refcursor)
AS
BEGIN
    open resultSet for
        SELECT DISTINCT 
            (tb.CODIGO||separador||tb.NOMBRE) AS Campo
            FROM TABLA tb
            WHERE 
                tb.CODIGO = codigo 
                and concat(tb.IDENTIFICADOR,tb.TECLA) in (Identificadores);
                -- and concat(tb.IDENTIFICADOR,tb.TECLA) in ('FR45');
END;
/
```

The problem arises when executing the stored procedure, since the result is: "procedure successfully completed", but does not show any data. In contrast, if you only change the WHERE clause in the Identifiers variable by its value (hardcode the value, as in the commented line), it does return all the rows that correspond. I do not understand xq if you pass the same value as parameter does not work. So I execute the proce:

```
set serveroutput on;
variable rs refcursor;
exec SP_test('FR45','|', '1',:rs);
print rs;
```

There is no error with any of the other parameters, and although I have tried sending only "FR45" as parameter Identifiers, the application could send a list of codes separated by "," (from there importing of using IN and not a simple EQUAL) . I've already tried using "instr ()" instead of IN and even creating views ... and nothing.

It's more than 4 days and I can not find a solution: (please .. any idea what I should do so that the procedure recognizes the Identifiers parameter in the IN clause and returns the column of data that I need? :(

PS I had the same procedure In SQL-Server and it worked perfect..

Comment: Please either [post in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/152099), or on [the Spanish-language site](https://es.stackoverflow.com).

Comment: Does your table have a column called `identifiers`, as well as one called `identifier`? This could be a naming scope clash. You can't pass a comma-seperated list of values to an `in()` clause as a bind variable, though, if that is your goal. Maybe pass a collection of values instead?

Comment: No, there's no column called 'identifiers' nor 'identifier'. I would adapt the string sent in the parameter "Identificadores", so don't have to use commas... but i haven't thought about sending a collenction of values. Have no idea on how to do it. My first problem now is: Why don't accetp the parameter, but the hardcoded value in the IN clause ? :/ Any idea? :(

Comment: Sorry, I was looking at the translated post, and didn't notice the names changed too... does your table have a column called `identificadores`?

Comment: No. The table names aren't similar to any reservated word. The column names in the table are: Codigo, Nombre, Identificador and Tecla.

Comment: I recreated your procedure (using the SCOTT.EMP table since I don't have your tables) and it works with a variable name in the IN condition just as well as with a hard-coded value.

Comment: Typo alert: your procedure name is `SP_test` but later you call `SPtest`. Do you also, actually, have another procedure, called `SPtest`?

Comment: I wrote it wrong here, but I have already edited it. There is no SPtest, when I was testing my procedure, I called it well with the underscore. @mathguy, i was testing on SQL Developer 11g, and it didn't show any output :( just: “Procedure successfully completed”.

Comment: @GeorginaDiaz - please edit the question to add the full table definition and the sample data that you expect to match your call. You have a scope name clash with `codig` - having parameter names the same as column names causes problems unless they're prefixed with the proc name, it's usually simpler to use something like `p_codig` for the parameter name. In this case that will cause too much data, not too little, but I'd suggest you change them anyway.